# IPA file size on IBM Mobile First

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I'm using MobileFirst PLatform 7.1 for mobile app development and I generate an Android and iOS enviroment with it. I generate the apk and ipa file for distribution and the apk file its a 10 MB file but the ipa file is over 43 MB... a huge difference!!. Both applications have the same common files and they don't have any native specific code. How can I reduce the ipa file?

Thanks

Comment: When you create a brand new project, does that blank app also weighs 43MB?

Comment: Yes... with a simple new app stars in 43 mb.

Comment: What is the complete build version of the MFP 7.1 you are using?
There was some work done in later iFixes to reduce the size of the SDK - generally removing optional feature components from Core SDK

Comment: @VivinK I'm using 7.1.0.00.20161006-0540

Answer (score 0):

Some things to look at:

1. Remove any unused code and libraries from the project
2. Remove unusedgenerated images from the native\resources folder or run them through pngcrush and alike
3. If using 3rd party libraries check if there are minified versions of them
4. Enable concatenation and minification: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_optimizing_apps_build_settings.html